# What is the easiest way to access my database from another computer?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I created a mySQL database with phpMyAdmin. In this database I stored the names and the location of my friends (along with an id as a primary key for the database). I wrote and run the following php script to retrieve these data from the database and project them on my local web server (XAMPP):

```
<?php

$dbServername = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'Friends';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM friends;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['id'], ' ', $row['name'], ' ', $row['location']. '<br>';

    }
}

?>
```

Now I want to access this database from my other computer where I need them to make some cool data visualisations at the front-end.

**My question is: What is the easiest way to access this database and retrieve its data from my other computer?**

Keep in mind that my ultimate goal is to create a basic website where I can store and update the data/info about my classmates at the back-end and visualise them at the front-end.

Comment: I use heidisql: https://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: If I'm correct, you used phpmyadmin to create a database and then copied that database to your local machine. You already have a way to interact with your database, namely phpmyadmin?

Comment: Thank you @raphael75 for your suggestion. I will have a look at it

Comment: Thank you @Loek for your response. Yes, If I understand right what you mean then yes you are right. The question is: do you mean that I just have to go at my browser at my other computer and log in the database or is it better to do this programmatically (as finally I want to build a basic app which will update the data of my friends at the back-end and visualise them at the front-end)?

Comment: For local development, it's always best to have a copy of your database. But in the end, you can just connect to your "online" database.

Comment: So you mean that I can connect to my database programmatically by running the same script as the above one but with changing the log-in credentials?

Comment: Create a mysql user that has access from a remote host: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html

Comment: @Universalis yeah, that's the whole idea of your script ;)

Comment: Cool @Loek, I guessed it so (even though I wonder a bit why then the other people here are suggesting other things). So what will be the exact credentials for logging in to my database from my other computer?

Comment: Do what @kerbholz said and use those credentials.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try. Thank you all for the help.